# remove double punctuation from list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, punctuation

I have a list of strings, but there are two sets of punctuation:

```
list_A = ['',
 " 'train set'",
 " 'toy train set'",
 " 'train track'",]
```

I am trying to remove the extra double quotation marks on each string, and don't want to remove the single ones in case it is an apostrophe.

I have tried:

```
new_list = []
for i in list_A:
    i = i.strip('"')
    new_list.append(i)
    print(i)
```

but still when I print the new_list, the punctuation is not gone, and when I print the second element of the list (the crux of the problem), they are still there

```
new_list
['',
 " 'train set'",
 " 'toy train set'",
 " 'train track'"]

new_list[1]
" 'train set'"
```

Comment: you are stripping double quotes, while you have single quotes in your data.

Comment: When I chance the strip to single quotes, I end up with new_list[1] returning " 'train set" which is even more confusing that strip. has only removed one of the single quotes

Comment: Because you have a freaking space in the beginning lol... where do you get the first list from? Is it a issue with how you initiate it or how u want to process a given data... if you hace given data just show some example...

Comment: @CarterB do you want quotes in the string?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that you can not use name 'list' for the variable.

I purpose you next code:

```
list1 = ['', " 'train set'", " 'toy train set'", " 'train track'"]
new_list = [i.replace("'", '') for i in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace()`

```
listt = ['',
 " 'train set'",
 " 'toy train set'",
 " 'train track'",]

newlist = []

for i in listt:
 new = i.replace("'","")
 newlist.append(new)
 
 print(newlist)
```

Another way to do it with list comprehension,

```
newlist = [i.replace("'","") for i in list]
```

Comment: I made a typo, please check now

Comment: When you put ```'``` in a list python will automatically add " around it to make it a string inside the list, so you need to remove all speech marks

Comment: @CarterB has your question been answered